# Which Audio file is played is not recognised

Tags: ios, uitableview, audio, chat, custom-cell

I am currently working on a chat application.
I have made a chatCellView and a controller .
I have made a view by coding for audio which contains a play button.
Now my problem is I am unable to recognise which audio file is being played. Need some guidance on how to achieve this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CellforRowAtIndexPath

AudioRecieveCell *cellRecieve= reuseIdentifier=@"AudioRecieveCell";
            cellRecieve=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

```
        cellRecieve.btnPlayResOutlet.tag=indexPath.row;


        [cellRecieve.btnPlayResOutlet addTarget:self action:@selector(playResAudioPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        return cellRecieve;
```

now make a selector as
-(void)playResAudioPressed:(id)sender{

UIButton *btnSender=(UIButton*)sender;
write your logic here

}